# How can one add a new blank scene to the blender game engine

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, scene

I am attempting to add a new scene to the blender game engine while the engine is running.

I am not attempting to add an existing scene that is in the file or an imported library, as with `bge.logic.addScene()` but rather create a new empty scene.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Scenes are always loaded from a blend file.